# ViewPager (RecyclerView) with custom item count doesn't update data properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

I've created an adapter (extending ListAdapter with DiffUtil.ItemCallback) for my RecyclerView. It's an ordinary adapter with several itemViewTypes, but it should be smth like cyclic, if API sends flag and dataset size is > 1 (made by overriding getItemCount() to return 1000 when conditions == true).
When I change app locale through app settings, my fragment recreates, data loads asynchronously (reactively, several times in a row, from different requests, depending on several rx fields, which causes data set to be a combination of data on different languages just after locale is changed (in the end all dataset is correctly translated btw) (make it more like synchronous is not possible because of feature specifics)), posting its values to LiveData, which triggers updates of recycler view, the problem appears:

**After last data set update some of the views (nearest to currently displayed and currently displayed) appear not to be translated.**

Final data set, which is posted to LiveData is translated correctly, it even has correct locale tag in its id. Also after views are recycled and we return back to them - they are also correct.
DiffUtil is computed correctly also (I've tried to return only false in item callbacks and recycler view still didn't update its view holders correctly).
When itemCount == list.size everything works fine.
When adapter is pretending to be cyclic and itemCount == 1000 - no.
Can somebody explain this behaviour and help to figure out how to solve this?

**Adapter Code Sample:**

```
private const val TYPE_0 = 0
private const val TYPE_1 = 1

class CyclicAdapter(
    val onClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit,
    val onCloseClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit,
) : ListAdapter<IViewData, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DataDiffCallback()) {

var isCyclic: Boolean = false
    set(value) {
        if (field != value) {
            field = value
        }
    }

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return if (isCyclic) {
        AdapterUtils.MAX_ITEMS // 1000
    } else {
        currentList.size
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        TYPE_0 -> Type0.from(parent)
        TYPE_1 -> Type1.from(parent)
        else -> throw ClassCastException("View Holder for ${viewType} is not specified")
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when (holder) {
        is Type0 -> {
            val item = getItem(
                AdapterUtils.actualPosition(
                    position,
                    currentList.size
                )
            ) as ViewData.Type0

            holder.setData(item, onClickedCallback)
        }
        is Type1 -> {
            val item = getItem(
                AdapterUtils.actualPosition(
                    position,
                    currentList.size
                )
            ) as ViewData.Type1

            holder.setData(item, onClickedCallback, onCloseClickedCallback)
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return when (val item = getItem(AdapterUtils.actualPosition(position, currentList.size))) {
        is ViewData.Type0 -> TYPE_0
        is ViewData.Type1 -> TYPE_1
        else -> throw ClassCastException("View Type for ${item.javaClass} is not specified")
    }
}

class Type0 private constructor(itemView: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun setData(
        viewData: ViewData.Type0,
        onClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit
    ) {
        (itemView as Type0View).apply {
            acceptData(viewData)
            setOnClickedCallback { url ->
                onClickedCallback(viewData.id,)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): Type0 {
            val view = Type0View(parent.context).apply {
                layoutParams =
                    LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            }
            return Type0(view)
        }
    }
}

class Type1 private constructor(itemView: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun setData(
        viewData: ViewData.Type1,
        onClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit,
        onCloseClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit
    ) {
        (itemView as Type1View).apply {
            acceptData(viewData)
            setOnClickedCallback { url ->
                onClickedCallback(viewData.id)
            }
            setOnCloseClickedCallback(onCloseClickedCallback)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): Type1 {
            val view = Type1View(parent.context).apply {
                layoutParams =
                    LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            }
            return Type1(view)
        }
    }
}
}
```

**ViewPager Code Sample:**

```
class CyclicViewPager @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr),
ICyclicViewPager {

private val cyclicViewPager: ViewPager2

private lateinit var onClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit
private lateinit var onCloseClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit
private lateinit var adapter: CyclicAdapter

init {
    LayoutInflater
        .from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.v_cyclic_view_pager, this, true)

    cyclicViewPager = findViewById(R.id.cyclic_view_pager)

    (cyclicViewPager.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).apply {
        addItemDecoration(SpacingDecorator().apply {
            dpBetweenItems = 12
        })
        clipToPadding = false
        clipChildren = false
        overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
    }

    cyclicViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
}

override fun initialize(
    onClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit,
    onCloseClickedCallback: (id: String) -> Unit
) {
    this.onClickedCallback = onClickedCallback
    this.onCloseClickedCallback = onCloseClickedCallback

    adapter = CyclicAdapter(
        onClickedCallback,
        onCloseClickedCallback,
    ).apply {
        stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
    }

    cyclicViewPager.adapter = adapter
}

override fun setState(viewPagerState: CyclicViewPagerState) {

    when (viewPagerState.cyclicityState) {

        is CyclicViewPagerState.CyclicityState.Enabled -> {
            adapter.submitList(viewPagerState.pages) {
                adapter.isCyclic = true

                cyclicViewPager.post {
                    cyclicViewPager.setCurrentItem(
                        // Setting view pager item to +- 500
                        AdapterUtils.getCyclicInitialPosition(
                            adapter.currentList.size
                        ), false
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        is CyclicViewPagerState.CyclicityState.Disabled -> {
            if (viewPagerState.pages.size == 1 && adapter.isCyclic) {
                cyclicViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false)
                adapter.isCyclic = false
            }

            adapter.submitList(viewPagerState.pages)
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Adapter Utils Code:**

```
object AdapterUtils {
const val MAX_ITEMS = 1000

fun actualPosition(position: Int, listSize: Int): Int {
    return if (listSize == 0) {
        0
    } else {
        (position + listSize) % listSize
    }
}

fun getCyclicInitialPosition(listSize: Int): Int {
    return if (listSize > 0) {
        MAX_ITEMS / 2 - ((MAX_ITEMS / 2) % listSize)
    } else {
        0
    }
}
}
```

Have tried not to use default itemView variable of RecyclerView (became even worse).
Tried to make diff utils always return false, to check if it calculates diff correctly (yes, correctly)
Tried to add locale tags to ids of data set items (didn't help to solve)
Tried to post empty dataset on locale change before setting new data to it (shame on me, shouldn't even think about it)
Tried do add debounce to rx to make it wait a bit before update (didn't help)

**UPD:** When I call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() manually, which is not the preferred way, everything works fine, so the question is why ListAdapter doesn't dispatch notify callbacks properly in my case?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `ListAdapter` is that it doesn't **clearly** state that you need to supply a new list for it to function.

In other words, [the documentation says](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter.java;l=119): (and I quote the source code):

```
    /**
     * Submits a new list to be diffed, and displayed.
     * <p>
     * If a list is already being displayed, a diff will be computed on a background thread, which
     * will dispatch Adapter.notifyItem events on the main thread.
     *
     * @param list The new list to be displayed.
     */
    public void submitList(@Nullable List<T> list) {
        mDiffer.submitList(list);
    }
```

The key word being **new** list.

However, as you can see there, all the adapter does is defer to the `DiffUtil` and calls `submitList` there.

So when you [look at the actual source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/AsyncListDiffer.java;l=235) of the `AsyncListDiffer` you will notice it does, at the beginning of its code block:

```
        if (newList == mList) {
            // nothing to do (Note - still had to inc generation, since may have ongoing work)
            if (commitCallback != null) {
                commitCallback.run();
            }
            return;
        }
```

In other words, **if the new list (reference) is the same as the old one, regardless of their contents, don't do anything**.

This may sound cool but it means that if you have this code, the adapter will not really update:

(pseudo...)

```
var list1 = mutableListOf(...) 
adapter.submitList(list1)

list1.add(...)
adapter.submitList(list1)
```

The reason is list1 is the same reference your adapter has, so the differ exits prematurely, and doesn't dispatch any changes to the adapter.

Quite obscure, I know.

The solution, as pointed in many SO answers is to create a copy of the list itself.

Most users do

```
var list1 = mutableListOf(...) 
adapter.submitList(list1)

var list2 = list1.toMutableList()
list2.add(...)
adapter.submitList(list2)
```

The call to `toMutableList()` creates a new list containing the items of `list1` and so the comparison above `if (newList == mList) {` should now be false and the normal code should execute.

#### UPDATE

Keep in mind that a lot of developers make the mistake of...

```
var list = mutableListOf...
adapter.submitList(list)

list.add(xxx)

adapter.submitList(list.toList())
```

This doesn't work, because the new list you create, is referencing *the same objects the adapter has*. This means that both lists `list` and `list.toList()` are pointing to the same things despite being two instances of an ArrayList.
But the side-effect is that `DiffUtil` compares the items and they are the same, so no diff is dispatched to the adapter either.

The correct sequence is...

```
val list = mutableListOf(...)
adapter.submitList(list.toList())

// Make a copy first, so we can alter it as we please without the *current list held by the adapter* from being affected.
var modified = list.toMutableList()
modified.add(...)
adapter.submitList(modified)
```

Comment: my fault, didn't mention that in my ViewModel I don't modify existing list, I ALWAYS create a new list, and put it as a field to state data class, which is posted to LiveData, which triggers submitting list to adapter. So in my case this solution will not affect anything

Comment: No problem though it's difficult to see where your problem may be, given the complexity of your adapter and the lack of any extra code. What did you debug so far? Have your checked that everytime you call `submitList` that the list reference is different? Have you put breakpoints in your adapter/differ/etc. to see if things are dispatched? In short, a RV *does work* with a listAdapter, so to pinpoint why it doesn't for you, you're going to need to dig a bit deeper and come up a point where your code does something it shouldn't.

Comment: Have you tried manually constructing a new list? does that work instead? could your data class/model not correctly implement Equals/Hash? Could you be accidentally modifying the old list (via its reference) before your `post` the livedata? Remember this is Java/JVM code, unless you explicitly create new references of the list, and / or copies of the contents, the pointers all point to the same thing.

Comment: logged hash codes of lists in my setState method. They are not the same. And some of the items are updated correctly. But as we are in centre of view pager, on position 500 e.x., when I scroll back, to 499, 498, then 499 and 498 are not updated

Comment: Hmmm i'm not sure, do you have a sample project demonstrating this issue?

Comment: quickly made a repository with demo of this feature, it shows the problem: https://github.com/ig-egorov/ViewPagerProblem

Comment: I'll do my very best to take a quick look today, work permitting.

Comment: Took a quick glance. It's a bit convoluted (with all the cyclic stuff that I didn't verify if it was interfering or not). It *looks* like everything is wired correctly. Things I frowned upon (in no part. order): 1. the cyclic stuff could be confusing the adapter logic. 2. The fragments are not being updated (when it fails) b/c `onBindViewHolder` is not called there. 3. The empty interface `IViewData` not sure if this was a simplification, but I don't see why is that needed there. 4. FrameLayouts are quite bad at responding to updates (they do not fw events to children), but this is irrelevant.

Comment: ..irrelevant because onBindVH is not called and this means nothing is updated. What *I* would try, is to use Fragments (instead of views) for your ViewPager, and have the data model, simply model the data needed by the fragment. Still, I'm not sure what exactly is going on, as you correctly construct NEW items every time. What you can do if you don't want to change your code, is simply re-create the adapter instead of simply submit list. I'll post another answer with that idea for you to explore on the side.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at [your sample](https://github.com/ig-egorov/ViewPagerProblem) in GitHub, I was able to reproduce the issue. With only about 30-40 minutes of playing with it, I can say that I'm not 100% sure what component is not updating.

Things I've noticed.

1. The `onBindViewHolder` method is not called when you change the locale (except maybe the 1st time?).
2. I do not understand why the need to `post` to the adapter after you've submitted the list in the callback:

```
                       cyclicViewPager.setCurrentItem(
                            // Setting view pager item to +- 500
                            AdapterUtils.getCyclicInitialPosition(
                                adapter.currentList.size
                            ), false
                        )
```

Why ? This means the user loses their current position.

Why not keep the existing?

3. I noticed you do `cyclicViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3` this effectively disables the RecyclerView "logic" for handling changes, and uses instead the usual ViewPager state adapter logic of "prefetching/keeping" N (3 in your case) pages in "advance".
   At first I thought this was causing issues, but removing it (which sets it to -1 which is the default and the "use RecyclerView" value, didn't make a big change (though I did notice *some* changes here and there, as in it would sometimes update the current one -but not the next ones within 2~3 pages).

The documentation says:

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the currently visible page(s). Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed. Set this to OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT to use RecyclerView's caching strategy.

So I would have imagined that the default value would be aided by the ListAdapter and its DiffUtil. Doesn't seem to be the case.

4. What I *did* try (among a few other things) was to see if the issue was in the actual adapter (or at least the viewPager dependency on its adapter). I ran out of time (work!) but I noticed that if you do:

```
  override fun setState(viewPagerState: CyclicViewPagerState) {
        when (viewPagerState.cyclicityState) {
            is CyclicViewPagerState.CyclicityState.Enabled -> {
                
                // call initialize again, to recreate the adapter
                initialize(this.onClickedCallback, this.onCloseClickedCallback)

                adapter.submitList(viewPagerState.pages) {
                    adapter.isCyclic = true
                    // Setting vp item to ... (code omitted for brevity)
                }
```

This works. It's *theoretically less efficient* as you're recreating the whole adapter, but in your example you're effectively creating an ENTIRE new set of data changing every ID, so in terms of performance, I'd argue this is more efficient as there's no need to recalculate changes and dispatch them, since to the eyes of the Diff Util, all the rows are different. By recreating the adapter, well... the VP has to reinit anyway.

I noticed this worked fine in your example.

I went ahead and added two more things, because the "silly" adapter cannot reliably tell you which position is the current... you can naively save it:

In `CyclicViewPager`:

```
var currentPos: Int = 0
```

```
init {
   ...
   this.cyclicViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int)
                currentPos = position
            }
        })
}
```

And then

```
            is CyclicViewPagerState.CyclicityState.Enabled -> {
                initialize(this.onClickedCallback, this.onCloseClickedCallback)

                adapter.submitList(viewPagerState.pages) {
                    adapter.isCyclic = true
                    if (adapter.currentList.size <= currentPos) {
                        cyclicViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPos, false)
                    } else {
                        cyclicViewPager.setCurrentItem(
                            // Setting view pager item to +- 500
                            AdapterUtils.getCyclicInitialPosition(
                                adapter.currentList.size
                            ), false
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

This does work, but of course, you're recreating the entire VP adapter again, so it may not be desired.

At this point, I'd either need to spend much more time trying to figure out which part of VP, RV, or its dependencies is not "dispatching" the correct data. My guess would be somewhere around some silly ViewPager optimization combined with Android terribly unreliable View system, not picking a message in the queue; but I may be also terribly wrong ;)

I hope someone smarter and/or with more coffee in their system can find out a simpler solution.

(all in all, I found the sample project relatively easy to navigate, but the design of your data a bit convoluted, but... as it was a sample, it's hard to tell what "real-life" data structures you really have).

Comment: thanks for such detailed response

Comment: In sample the data was designed in such a way as it is designed in real project, though it may cause described problem to appear, so included it in sample. I'll try to work around your recommendations, seems there are many things to think about, and hope they will help to solve this in real project

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I don't have a magic bullet. In my limited xp, most of the RecyclerView/Adapter problems tend to be related to the user doing something _strange_, and while I can't say you are, the data in the sample is not 100% 'simple', and it may be causing some issues. I'd try to -if possible-, simplify the data that ultimately reaches the adapter/VP. I'm not sure how many ViewHolders you need in the real app but maybe let the VH handle the "changes" when it comes to the UI, your ViewHOlders are quite "empty" as they are.